# How do I optimize this PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, stress-testing

For stress test, I execute the following tables in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tempxx (sid numeric(10,0));

CREATE TABLE temptab( 
r1 numeric(10,0),
r2 numeric(10,0),
r3 numeric(10,0),
v1 varchar(40),
v2 varchar(40));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX stemptab ON temptab (r1 ASC,r2 ASC);

INSERT INTO tempxx VALUES (1);
```

Then I use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stresstest1() RETURNS VOID
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ 
DECLARE 
   S1 TIMESTAMP;
   S2 TIMESTAMP;
   S3 TIMESTAMP;
   xm1 int;
BEGIN
   UPDATE tempxx SET sid=sid+1;

   S1:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

   FOR REC IN 1..100000 LOOP
      UPDATE TEMPXX SET SID=SID+1 returning SID into xm1;
      INSERT INTO TEMPTAB VALUES (xm1,REC,rec,'TEST '||REC,'TEST2 '||REC);
   END LOOP;

   S2:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   S3:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

   RAISE NOTICE '%','STARTED AT '||S1||' TO '||S2||' TO '||S3||' '||(S2-S1)||' '||(S3-S1);
END
$$;

SELECT stresstest1();
```

It takes about 14m. I want to shorten this period. I made these adjustments, but the result has not changed.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers = '1GB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET work_mem = '5242kB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET random_page_cost = '4';
```

How can I optimize the query to take shorter time? Can I optimize the 'update' and 'insert' commands in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Optimizations in expected order of impact:

- your stress test mostly writes, so you should optimize for that:
  increase `max_wal_size` quite a lot to reduce the number of checkpoints (look at the PostgreSQL log file for an explanation)
- if you can, use a sequence for a number generator instead of `tempxx`
- use `bigint` for `tempxx.sid`
- create your database cluster running `initdb` with a bigger `--wal-segsize` to get fewer WAL switches